# Call parent class method (with this context) in child class

Tags: javascript

I've used JS frameworks in which interaction with a child component calls an action on a parent component. I'm trying to do something similar in plain JS, but don't really know how. I'm trying to bind the parent this, to the action passed down to the child. But can't make it work.

Should I just be using events instead? And why use events over this sort of approach?

Here's the basics of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(){
        for (let id=0; id<100; id++){
            this.children.push(new Child(id, this.updateParent.bind(this)))
        }
    }
    property = "Parent Property";
    children;
    updateParent(childId){
        // Update parent using child Id
        // I want to use this.property or other this.methods
    }
}

class Child {
    constructor(id, updateParent){

        // Create HTML element
        // Register event for element interaction
        // Upon interaction --
            updateParent(id)
    }
}

const parent = new Parent()
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/1oLp0ntj/

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be working exactly as I'd hoped. It was the binding that wasn't working for me. 'This' was returning undefined. Thanks a lot, I'll take a look through my code and see what I've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems to be almost working, here it is with some tweaks and logging.

Callback methods are a legit way of event handling, try both and use whichever is more comfortable for the kinds of interactions you need in your system.

```js
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.children = []
    for (let id = 0; id < 10; id++) {
      this.children.push(new Child(id, this.updateParent.bind(this)))
    }
  }
  childCount = 0
  updateParent(childId) {
    console.log(`Child ${childId} updating Parent. youngest=${this.youngestChild}, count=${this.childCount}`)
    this.youngestChild = childId;
    this.childCount += 1;
  }
}

class Child {
  constructor(id, updateParent) {
    console.log("Child Born:", id)
    this.id = id
    updateParent(id)
  }
}

const parent = new Parent()
console.log(parent.children)
```

Comment: Thanks, as much as anything I wasn't sure if this was a legitimate way to go. It seems more natural and proper to pass methods rather than creating and calling additional events. I know I'm using an event anyway, but all the same...

Comment: You might want to just do the bind once, and store it, and then pass that in, and also split up the "birthing" into a different method from the parent initialisation, but otherwise what you're doing makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the children first.

Take a look at this:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(){
          this.children = [];
        for (let id=0; id<100; id++){
            this.children.push(new Child(id, this.updateParent.bind(this)))
        }
    }
    property = "Parent Property";
    children;
    updateParent(childId){
        // Update parent using child Id
        // I want to use this.property or other this.methods
        console.log("Parent updated from Child ID: "+childId);
    }
}

class Child {
    constructor(id, updateParent){

        // Create HTML element
        // Register event for element interaction
        // Upon interaction --
            updateParent(id)
    }
}

const parent = new Parent()
```